# How do I uninstall nodejs installed from pkg (Mac OS X)?

Tags: node.js, pkg-file

I installed NodeJS from pkg file on my Mac. Now I need to uninstall it. Tell me please how to do it.
I tried to remove files from this list:

> lsbom -f -l -s -pf /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.pkg.bom

But node is still on my computer.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

I ran:

```
lsbom -f -l -s -pf /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.pkg.bom \
| while read i; do
  sudo rm /usr/local/${i}
done
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node \
     /usr/local/lib/node_modules \
     /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.*
```

Coded into [gist 2697848](https://gist.github.com/nicerobot/2697848)

*Update*
It seems the receipts `.bom` file name may have changed so you may need to replace `org.nodejs.pkg.bom` with `org.nodejs.node.pkg.bom` in the above. The gist has been updated accordingly.

Comment: Very helpful.  Only thing I would add is that node 0.4 ish installed in /usr, not /usr/local.  So "sudo rm /usr/local/${i}" needs to be changed.  For me I did "sudo rm /${i}" since the bom files where pathed liked: "./usr/bin/node"

Comment: I created a [gist](https://raw.github.com/gist/2697848/uninstall-node.sh) for it. Use it at your own risk.

Comment: @nicerobot Thanks for the gist/script! Probably should point out to others that the actual [gist page for that script is here](https://gist.github.com/nicerobot/2697848). Also, being a n00b to running .sh scripts myself, I had to `$ chmod u+x uninstall-node.sh` and then `$ ./uninstall-node.sh` before it worked for me. :)

Comment: @nicerobot and micky-hulse this is most excellent! +1 for both of you.
also, try > "which node" or "which npm" after executing the script to see if you still have node/npm installed (or at least, one of the installed versions is gone)

Comment: yea it worked, cool answer. whatever I had a little something left over and just finished that right off with `rm -rf /Users/me/local/bin/node` now rocking node unstable!

Comment: make sure you only delete `/var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.*` when every worked successfully. I run the command once, and I had a lot of erreor like `rm: /usr/local/./lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/node_modules/is-absolute/package.json: No such file or directory`.

But it was too late, by the end of the script the bom is definitely deleted.
Unable to fix and rerun the script

Comment: @Gomino when running things like this, I would put it more generally, you REALLY should check your system and the script to understand if it’s going to do what you want. The script was written against older versions of macOS and Node.js so may require updates.

Comment: Yeah for sure, I still upvoted your answer by the way 

Comment: I've also had to run the first command for `/var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.npm.pkg.bom`.

Answer (score 132):

If you installed Node from their [website](http://nodejs.org), try this:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/{bin/{node,npm},lib/node_modules/npm,lib/node,share/man/*/node.*}
```

This worked for me, but if you have any questions, my GitHub is 'mnafricano'.

Comment: I had mine installed in /opt/local/bin

Comment: That's probably because you were using MacPorts

Comment: This worked for me after @nicerobot's script (higher-rated answer) failed, cacophonously. Uninstalled and reinstalled 0.10.32.

Comment: and also missing `/usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d`

Comment: missing `/var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.*`

Answer (score 82):

Following previous posts, here is the full list I used

```
sudo npm uninstall npm -g
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/node /Users/$USER/.npm
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/node
sudo rm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node.1
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d
brew install node
```

Comment: THANK YOU. My MySQL stopped working so I just needed to remove it, this + a restart did the trick.

Comment: I also had to remove two additional files: `/usr/local/share/doc/node/gdbinit` and `/usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp`

Comment: got 2 errors as rm: /usr/local/bin/node: No such file or directory, rm: /usr/local/share/man/man1/node.1: No such file or directory

Answer (score 11):

In order to delete the 'native' node.js installation, I have used the method suggested in previous answers `sudo npm uninstall npm -g`, with additional `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.*`.

BUT, I had to also delete the following two directories:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/node /Users/$USER/.npm
```

Only after that I could install node.js with Homebrew.

Comment: was not enough for me - had to also ```sudo rm /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/share/man/man1/node.1 /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use my forked gist:
https://gist.github.com/ryangatchalian912/75c6894c3f3143fef366d25eb63437ab

Copy and paste these commands into your **Terminal**:

```
curl -ksO https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ryangatchalian912/75c6894c3f3143fef366d25eb63437ab/raw/59c25be64e5555415726bfa824ae41ae1b4539b9/uninstall-node.sh
chmod +x ./uninstall-node.sh
sudo ./uninstall-node.sh > tester.txt
rm uninstall-node.sh
```

It works on Mac OSX Big Sur (11.4+).

Comment: Thank you, it works on OS X 10.11 (El Capitan)

Comment: Thank you. Confirmed working on OSX 12.3 / M1 Pro

Comment: Thank you ,it works on macOS monterey version 12.4

Comment: Still working on macOS Ventura :)

Answer (score 8):

This is the full list of commands I used (Many thanks to the posters above):

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/node /Users/$USER/.npm
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/node
sudo rm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node.1
brew install node
```

Answer (score 6):

Use npm to uninstall. Just running `sudo npm uninstall npm -g` removes all the files.
To get rid of the extraneous stuff like bash pathnames run this (from nicerobot's answer):

`sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node \
     /usr/local/lib/node_modules \
     /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.*`

Answer (score 5):

I took AhrB's list, while appended three more files. Here is the full list I have used:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/node /Users/$USER/.npm
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/node
sudo rm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node.1
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/npm
sudo rm /usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d
# In case you want to reinstall node with HomeBrew:
# brew install node
```

Comment: Worked great for me! Skip the last line to leave node uninstalled on your system.

Comment: Thanks @Rich for the comment, I have commented out the last line.

Answer (score 3):

A little convenience script expanding on previous answers.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Uninstall node.js
# 
# Options:
#
# -d Actually delete files, otherwise the script just _prints_ a command to delete.
# -p Installation prefix. Default /usr/local
# -f BOM file. Default /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.pkg.bom

CMD="echo sudo rm -fr"
BOM_FILE="/var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.pkg.bom"
PREFIX="/usr/local"

while getopts "dp:f:" arg; do
    case $arg in
        d)
            CMD="sudo rm -fr"
            ;;
        p)
            PREFIX=$arg
            ;;
        f)
            BOM_FILE=$arg
            ;;
    esac
done

lsbom -f -l -s -pf ${BOM_FILE} \
    | while read i; do
          $CMD ${PREFIX}/${i}
      done

$CMD ${PREFIX}/lib/node \
     ${PREFIX}/lib/node_modules \
     ${BOM_FILE}
```

Save it to file and run with:

```
# bash filename.sh
```

Answer (score 3):

#### A decent way to uninstall node installed from pkg

##### See what is in db/receipts

`ls /var/db/receipts/org.node*`

##### Peek into the relevant bom files noting the paths listed

- `lsbom -f -l -s -pf /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.node.pkg.bom`
- `lsbom -f -l -s -pf /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.npm.pkg.bom`

##### Do the deletes. Use prefix on remove depending on the paths above.

`lsbom -f -l -s -pf /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.node.pkg.bom | while read i; do sudo rm /${i}; done`

`lsbom -f -l -s -pf /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.npm.pkg.bom | while read i; do sudo rm /${i}; done`

##### Remove the remaining folders

- `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules`
- `sudo rm -rf /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.*`

##### Check it is really gone

- `which node`
- `which npm`

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the following files too since brew complained in install later after manually removing all files.

```
/usr/local/share/doc/node/gdbinit

/usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
```

and then do the following

```
brew install node 

brew link node
```

Comment: Use markup to format your code or pathes as monotype.

Comment: Question is about uninstalling not installing.. you probably misspell it should be .....brew uninstall node

Answer (score 0):

The following worked after trial and error, and these directories were not writable so, I removed them and finally was able to get node & npm replaced.

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/systemtap
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/doc/node
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar/node/9.11.1
brew install node
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/node-9.11.1.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/xxx/Library/Caches/Homebrew/node-9.11.1.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring node-9.11.1.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/node/9.11.1: 5,125 files, 49.7MB

node -v
v9.11.1
npm -v
5.6.0
```

Comment: I modified your formatting. You can select a block of text and click the curly brace icon to get monospace text. Or indent every line with four spaces if you're a masochist.

Answer (score 0):

I also installed via `.pkg`, I had a lot of permission errors lately and wanted to use `nvm` so had to uninstall the current version. Found the below script from [here](https://medium.com/@abuabdirohman/how-to-uninstall-node-js-that-installed-via-pkg-on-macos-ffab7cd852bb)

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/{bin/{node,npm},lib/node_modules/npm,lib/node,share/man/*/node.*}
```