# Upgrade Node.js to the latest version on Mac OS

Tags: macos, node.js, upgrade

Currently I am using Node.js v0.6.16 on Mac OS X 10.7.4. Now I want to upgrade it to the latest Node.js v0.8.1. But after downloading and installing the latest package file from nodejs.org, I found that system is still using v0.6.16 instead of v0.8.1 when I typed "node -v" in a terminal. Is there any step that I have missed? Or, should I thoroughly uninstall the old version before installing the latest one?

BTW, I know that nvm can help to manage the nodejs package

https://github.com/creationix/nvm/

Is there any way to upgrade the Node.js without using it?

I have googled this problem, but it seems to me that there is no very clear answer to this question for the latest Node.js.

Comment: Not sure on an answer, but for clarification is a Node process running when you update it?

Comment: No, I don't think there is any Node process running. And after restarting the OS, the "node -v" command still shows v0.6.16 is running.

Comment: You might want to first double check you have it installed with `brew` https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/101090/list-of-all-packages-installed-using-homebrew

Comment: Folks - this is a 6 year old question and with some equally old answers. No doubt that they were the best practices back then. But as of 2018, `brew upgrade node` should work just fine. Please see the answer by wprl below.

Comment: @pscl As of February 2019, the [npm website](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm) actually recommends using a Node version manager like `n` or `nvm` to install and upgrade both Node and npm.

Comment: You can just download the latest installer from the official website. https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: I got this issue, because of unnecessary import 'node-sass', which was not required, by remove that import source worked very well. this one is 2021 issue with similar error message inside react.

Comment: Just use "nvm install <version>"

Answer (score 1955, accepted):

Here's how I successfully upgraded from `v0.8.18` to `v0.10.20` **without any other requirements** like brew etc, (type these commands in the terminal):

1. `sudo npm cache clean -f` (force) clear you npm cache
2. `sudo npm install -g n` install [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) (this might take a while)
3. `sudo n stable` upgrade to the current stable version

*Note that `sudo` might prompt your password.*

*Additional note regarding step 3: `stable` can be exchanged for `latest`, `lts` (long term support) or any specific version number such as `0.10.20`.*

If the version number doesn't show up when typing `node -v`, you might have to reboot.

These instructions are found here as well: [davidwalsh.name/upgrade-nodejs](https://davidwalsh.name/upgrade-nodejs)
More info about the **n** package found here: [npmjs.com/package/n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n)
More info about Node.js' release schedule: [github.com/nodejs/Release](https://github.com/nodejs/Release#release-schedule)

Comment: worked to update node from v0.10 to v0.12 in macos x snow leopard. Thank you.

Comment: FWIW you can use 'n lts' to install the long term support version rather than the current stable version (i.e. 4.4.3 instead of 5.10.1 at the time of writing)

Comment: Note step 1 force clears your cache. You'll get the warning: npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.

Comment: Brew is occurring error. This is the correct answer, currently.

Comment: you can do `sudo n latest` as the final step also

Comment: `sudo n lts` as the last step gets you a Long Term Support version

Comment: Perfect @osx node upgraded to 9.8.0

Comment: Thanks, It helped as brew with sudo is no longer supported.

Comment: I didn't need to clear my cache, but maybe I made a mistake in not doing so

Comment: I tried a couple of from this answer thread But Only This Solutions works for me. @Johan Dettmar, Thanks for the answer. I upgraded from 8.x to 10.10.0

Comment: This worked, but no one explains what the commands why installing "n" helps. I just figured out today that "n" is a Node.js version manager, as somewhat explained on the npm js website - https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm

Comment: Doing this is enough npm cache clean -f & npm install -g node

Comment: Working on Mojave `10.14.12` to upgrade Node form 8 to v14.17.5 and npm to 6.14.14.

Comment: This does not set the active node version for homebrew. How do I set the active node version?

Answer (score 1035):

If you initially installed [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh), run:

```
brew update
brew upgrade node
npm install -g npm
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
brew update && brew upgrade node && npm install -g npm
```

---

A convenient way to change versions is to use [n](https://github.com/tj/n):

```
brew install n
```

To install the latest version of Node.js with n:

```
n latest
```

Or, to install the latest LTS version with n:

```
n lts
```

---

Alternatively, you could use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) instead of n:

```
brew install nvm
```

To install the latest version of Node.js with nvm:

```
nvm install node
```

---

*If you installed via a package, then download the latest version from [nodejs.org](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node).
See [Installing Node.js and updating npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node).*

Comment: Hi SoloBold, thanks for your reply. I didn't use brew. I install the orignal v0.6.16 from the pkg file provided by nodejs.org. So I can't use "brew update node".

Comment: @afterglowlee You might try uninstalling the old node before reinstalling the new one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044788/how-do-i-uninstall-nodejs-installed-from-pkg-mac-os-x

Comment: Yeah. It seems to be the only way currently to do it. I will try and see if it works.

Comment: Thoroughly removing and reinstalling NodeJS works. But I really suspect if it is the proper way to upgrade NodeJS on Mac OS. So as a summary, on Mac OS, we'd better use some tools, such as nvm and brew, to manage the version of NodeJS.

Comment: Interestingly, the brew formula for node seems to just do a `./configure && make install;` I'm not sure what exactly brew does in the upgrade process, but it should be reproducible by hand if necessary.  A place to start, anyway :) https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/9ff0a1da93771f44610c8f68d768ddba30becde7/Library/Formula/node.rb

Comment: Yeah, it also seems weird to me. Maybe I am quite a newbie to NodeJS. Now I am using nvm to manage my NodeJS version. Nvm downloaded the sourcecode of v0.8.1 and make a couple of links:  


`ln -fs out/Release/node node`
`out/Release/node tools/installer.js install `

`cp -rf src/node.h /Users/user/projects/nvm/v0.8.1/include/node/`

`ln -sf ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js` `/Users/user/projects/nvm/v0.8.1/bin/npm`
`shebang #!/Users/user/projects/nvm/v0.8.1/bin/node` 

`Now using node v0.8.1`

There must be some way to configure it in Mac OS

Comment: I just upvoted this answer, but after 7 mins wait, brew told me installation failed... I also tried `port upgrade node`, but brew already messed up the package and port can't find node now... Finally I went to nodejs.org to download the installation package, and boom! Everything goes well, including the npm!

Comment: @Jinzhao It's recommended not to install more than one of Homebrew, MacPorts, or Fink.

Comment: I am using Homebrew and everything works except being able to update npm. I get `npm WARN package.json github-url-from-git@1.1.1 No repository field.
/usr/local/bin/npm -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
npm@1.5.0-alpha-1 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm`

Comment: @user2197606 have you run brew doctor and brew update recently?

Comment: in current brew version it states 
"If you update npm itself, do NOT use the npm update command.
The upstream-recommended way to update npm is:  npm install -g npm@latest"

Comment: @Pascal they've since fixed the `npm update -g npm` command. https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/commit/f2bfb09f278ad979560920a83bb022d0dd9a6133

Comment: I hate update packages with `brew` by symlinks problems, for this time i used the node `dpkg`installer.

Comment: I used homebrew to remove node, then followed the instructions given. The only thing I needed to do was npm install -g  n for and then use n stable to use the most current node version

Comment: Run `npm install -g node` after following above instructions if your node version is still not updated.

Comment: You can also simply run: `npm i -g npm`.

Comment: I strongly advise against installing nvm via brew, you can see that mentioned in the readme on https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Personally I have a hard time remove outdated nvm installed via brew.
Also when you have node, npm, nvm with non compatible across all major version this create a triangle of dependencies. It's really hard to reason what's going on when things do not work. I would just neutralize nvm before upgrading node/npm.

Comment: i wish there was some way to determine whether I installed a piece of software using brew, port, or some other mechanism, because I can never remember!

Comment: Much, much easier to use the `n` package (as other answers say) than having to deal with `brew`'s shenanigans.

Comment: I am on Mac :> brew upgrade node

Warning: node 17.5.0 already installed
but npm -v
6.14.15

Comment: brew update && brew upgrade node && npm install -g npm not work with error info:  Error: node not installed

Comment: Sorry for confusing here, my condition is complex. I installed brew and node in an intel chip and then restore it back arm chip. However, brew in arm use /opt/homebrew/Cellar not /usr/local/Cellar

Comment: Error: Cannot install in Homebrew on ARM processor in Intel default prefix (/usr/local)!

Answer (score 225):

Because this seems to be at the top of Google when searching for how to upgrade nodejs on mac I will offer my tip for anyone coming along in the future despite its age.

**Upgrading via NPM**
You can use the method described by @Mathias above or choose the following simpler method via the terminal.

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

After which you may opt to confirm the upgrade

```
node -v
```

Your nodejs should have upgraded to the latest version. If you wish to upgrade to a specific one say v0.8.19 then instead of

```
sudo n stable
```

use

```
sudo n 0.8.19
```

**EDIT**
Avoid using sudo unless you need to. Refer to comment by Steve in the comments

Comment: Why would you downvote an answer and not add a comment explaining why?

Comment: Because you advice to use sudo.

Comment: This works, but: is it really necessary to use the `--force` flag on `cache clean`? And I didn't need `sudo` for the first two commands.

Comment: Thanks @SteveBennett for adding that, I added sudo in order to include newbies who would need it, rather than leave them stranded. Moreover, having sudo will work in both cases.

Comment: Sometimes using sudo when it's not needed actually makes a mess, because you end up with files owned by `root`, which then can't be modified without sudo.

Comment: nice answer. Worked fine.

Comment: Can I do `sudo n latest`

Comment: I had then a couple of versions and was using the old (active). To change the version that is active [ n use 0.0.0] worked to swap versions.

Answer (score 78):

Go to http://nodejs.org and download and run the installer.
It works now - for me at least.

Comment: Do you know by any chance how installed jode.js updates in OS/X?

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you are asking

Comment: Sorry for the confusion (wrote in a hurry). I have installed node.js straight from the site's download link, Current Version: v0.8.14. When say v0.8.15 gets released, will I have to download it again, will it auto-update, will it call-home and inform me? With homebrew for example I was doing a brew upgrade (so it was up to me)

Comment: I don't think it will call home. You will have to check regularly and download the new version from their webpage i think. But im not 100% on this.

Comment: probably the easiest way here.

Comment: Likely the only thing that works in all cases. Just do it this way. But I somehow had another `node` installed in `/opt/local/bin` I had to remove cause it was taking precedence in my `PATH`.

Comment: Instead of messing around with brew and its errors, this way works!

Comment: This works well with intel Mac . Anyone tried this with M1 Mac?

Comment: @XSham shouldn't be any different? I would get nvm tho, it makes it super easy to switch version.

Comment: It works in mac

Answer (score 58):

You could install [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) and have multiple versions of Node.js installed.

```
curl https://raw.github.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | sh
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

and then run:

```
nvm install 0.8.22  #(or whatever version of Node.js you want)
```

you can see what versions you have installed with :

```
nvm list
```

and you can change between versions with:

```
nvm use 0.8.22
```

The great thing about using NVM is that you can test different versions alongside one another.  If different apps require different versions of Node.js, you can run them both.

Comment: I am using this method now. It seems to me that this is the best way to keep multiple versions running at the same machine.

Comment: If you set zch to be your default shell, that will not work. Installing nvm will error on trying to update the .bash_profile file. You will need to install https://github.com/lukechilds/zsh-nvm or edit the zch bash profile manually.

Answer (score 39):

I use Node version manager (called n) for it.

```
npm install -g n
```

then

```
n latest
```

OR

```
n stable
```

Comment: LTS version `n lts`

Answer (score 30):

### Simply go to node JS Website and install the latest version.

> Do install latest version instead of the recommended stable version. It will give you freedom to use latest ES6 Features on node.

Can be Found here [Node JS](https://nodejs.org/en/).

#### also to update **npm**, you will have to use this command.

`sudo npm i -g npm@latest`

> All your projects will work fine.

**Update: 2020** another good option is to use `nvm` for node which can then support multiple versions.
use `nvm install --lts` to always be able to update to latest node version use `nvm ls-remote` command to to check new versions of node.

---

Other option for mac :: `brew update && brew install node && npm -g npm`

Answer (score 27):

Upgrade the version of node **without installing any package**, not even nvm itself:

```
sudo npx n stable
```

---

**Explanations**:
This approach is similar to `Johan Dettmar`'s answer. The only difference is here the package [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) is not installed glabally in the local machine.

Comment: fast, clean and beautiful!

Comment: Clean and Beautiful. should be as acceptable answer.

Answer (score 25):

On macOS the homebrew recommended way is to run

```
brew install node
npm install -g npm@latest
```

[image: Screenshot of Terminal Commands]

Comment: It will install the truly latest version, not just the most current brewed version.

Answer (score 15):

There are five different ways (and counting?) to update Node.js on Mac:

1. Install the newer binary by downloading from nodejs.org
2. Update Node.js through Homebrew

   Command: `brew update && brew upgrade node`
3. Update Node.js using Node Version Manager (NVM)

   Command: `nvm install {version} && nvm use {version}`
4. Update Node.js using n package manager

   Command: `sudo n latest`
5. Update Node.js through MacPorts

   Command (same version update): `sudo port selfupdate && sudo port upgrade {version}`

If you are still using older MacOS version, it may be better to use lightweight, special-purpose package manager like `n` or `nvm`.

Comment: What if I just want to upgrade to the LST version? the `brew update && brew upgrade node` seems to work for the Current version

Answer (score 12):

I am able to upgrade the node using following command

```
nvm install node --reinstall-packages-from=node
```

Answer (score 10):

Now this works for me:

1. sudo npm install -g n
2. sudo n latest

Happy code!

Answer (score 9):

Pretty Simple.

```
  sudo npm i -g n
```

Then you can specify the version you want.

```
sudo n 12.8.0
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 7):

sadly, `n` doesn't worked for me. I use `node version manager or nvm` and it works like a charm. heres the link on how to install `nvm`: https://github.com/creationix/nvm#installation

- `nvm i 8.11.2` upgrade to latest LTS
- `nvm use 8.11.2` use it
- `node -v` check your latest version

Comment: This is the one that worked for me. I tried several of the top comments, but after following the steps, node is still stuck at v6. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me. thanks jannomeister. upvote for accepted answer please

Answer (score 6):

**Easy nad Safe Steps**

Step 1: Install NVM

```
brew install nvm
```

Step 2: Create a directory for NVM

```
mkdir ~/.nvm/
```

Step 3: Configure your environmental variables

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

PASTE BELOW CODE

```
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh

source ~/.bash_profile
```

Step 4: Double check your work

```
nvm ls
```

Step 5: Install Node

```
nvm install 9.x.x
```

Step6: Upgrade

```
nvm ls-remote

   v10.16.2   (LTS: Dubnium)
   v10.16.3   (Latest LTS: Dubnium) ..........
```

**nvm install v10.16.3**

**Troubleshooting**

```
Error Example #1
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules
brew uninstall node
brew install node --without-npm
echo prefix=~/.npm-packages >> ~/.npmrc
curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh
```

https://www.chrisjmendez.com/2018/02/07/install/

Comment: Simple & straight forward (Y)

Comment: those who are on zshrc should update `~./zprofile` instead of `~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 5):

Go to the website [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org) and download the latest pkg then install.
it works for me

I used brew to upgrade my node. It has installed but it located in `/usr/local/Cellar/node/5.5.0` and there is a default node in `/usr/local/bin/node` which bothers me. I don't want to make soft link because I don't really know how brew is organized. 
So I download the `pkg` file, installed and I got this info:

`Node.js` was installed at

```
/usr/local/bin/node
```

`npm` was installed at

```
/usr/local/bin/npm
```

Make sure that `/usr/local/bin` is in your $PATH.

Now the upgrade is completed

Answer (score 5):

These 2 methods I tried are not working:

1. Use npm

`sudo npm cache clean -f`

`sudo npm install -g n`

`sudo n stable`

2. Manual install node from official website (https://nodejs.org/en/)

After trying, `node -v` still shows the old version of node.

---

Below method works for me:

Step 1: Install nvm (for more details: https://github.com/creationix/nvm#installation)

Open terminal and type this command:

`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash`

Close terminal and reopen it.

Type this command to check if nvm is installed:

`command -v nvm`

[image]

Step 2: To download, compile, and install the latest release of node, type this:

`nvm install node` ("node" is an alias for the latest version)

To check if node gets the latest version (v10.11.0).

[image]

Installing the latest node also installs the latest npm.

Check if npm gets the latest version (6.4.1).

[image]

Comment: I found this method is not working for me now.
Here is how I did instead:
`npm install -g n`
`sudo n 10.11.0` (in my case, I just wanna update to 10.11.0)
Then it updated to 10.11.0 `node -v`

Comment: After trying alot, nvm install node, worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can run but you can't hide... At the end you will be using [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) anyways.

Comment: Or the 'n' package...  See Kenny West's answer if you'd like a simple package manager you can install via npm.

Answer (score 4):

You can just go to nodejs.org and download the newest package. It will update appropriately for you. NPM will be updated as well.

Comment: By far the easiest, if you initially installed it via de the website.

Answer (score 4):

I think the simplest way to use the newest version of Node.js is to get the newest Node.js pkg file in the website https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/
if you want to use different version of Node.js you can use nvm or n to manage it.

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo npm install -g n
```

and then

```
sudo n latest for linux/mac users
```

For Windows please reinstall node.

Answer (score 4):

for latest release:
`nvm install node`

specific version:
`nvm install 6.14.4`

https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Answer (score 3):

Nvm
Nvm is a script-based node version manager. You can install it easily with a curl and bash one-liner as described in the documentation. It's also available on Homebrew.

Assuming you have successfully installed nvm. The following will install the latest version of node.

```
 nvm install node --reinstall-packages-from=node
```

The last option installs all global npm packages over to your new version. This way packages like mocha and node-inspector keep working.

N
N is an npm-based node version manager. You can install it by installing first some version of node and then running `npm install -g n`.

Assuming you have successfully installed n. The following will install the latest version of node.

```
sudo n latest
```

Homebrew
Homebrew is one of the two popular package managers for Mac. Assuming you have previously installed node with brew install node. You can get up-to-date with formulae and upgrade to the latest Node.js version with the following.

```
1 brew update
2 brew upgrade node
```

MacPorts
MacPorts is the another package manager for Mac. The following will update the local ports tree to get access to updated versions. Then it will install the latest version of Node.js. This works even if you have previous version of the package installed.

```
1 sudo port selfupdate
2 sudo port install nodejs-devel
```

Comment: `brew upgrade node` is a breeze

Comment: This is what worked for me on OSX. I probably had NVM installed because `node -v` kept giving me `6.11.1` even after commands related to `n latest` and so on. The brew upgrade one worked. Thanks.

Comment: Macports isn't finding the "nodejs-devel" package for me.  I had to uninstall the old version and install the new one.

Answer (score 1):

Use nvm to upgrade node as per the project requirement..

install nvm through homebrew..
brew update
brew install nvm
mkdir ~/.nvm
nano ~/.bash_profile

In your .bash_profile file (you may be using an other file, according to your shell), add the following :

export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh

source ~/.bash_profile
echo $NVM_DIR

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use curl to upgrade node to the latest version. Run the following command:

```
curl "https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/node-${VERSION:-$(wget -qO- https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/ | sed -nE 's|.*>node-(.*)\.pkg</a>.*|\1|p')}.pkg" > "$HOME/Downloads/node-latest.pkg" && sudo installer -store -pkg "$HOME/Downloads/node-latest.pkg" -target "/"
```

Reference: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#macos

Answer (score 1):

First install `nvm` with this command:

`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash`

credirts to @Saviah Kao

Then install node:

`nvm install node --reinstall-packages-from=node`

credits to [@Elad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34810526/how-to-properly-upgrade-node-using-nvm)

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is go straight to the website
https://nodejs.org/en/download/
Click download the latest version and install pkg file.
After that you will get the latest node and npm version

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  This is what worked for me because I downloaded and  installed node.js **globally** from the node.js website.

What I did was Give NVM (Node Version Manager) a try. Please do the commands in the following order in your terminal

1. curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash
2. command -v nvm
3. nvm install node
4. node -v (to confirm the update)

Answer (score 0):

This is just to add some info for people who didn't have Node installed with *Homebrew* but getting that very error when trying to install packages with *npm* on *Mac OS X*.

I found this [good article](https://stackabuse.com/how-to-uninstall-node-js-from-mac-osx/) explaining how to completely remove *Node* whichever the way you originally installed it.

After *node*, *npm* and *n* were completely removed from my machine, I just reinstalled *Node.js* using the official *.pckg installer* from [Node website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and everything just went back to normal.

Hope this helps out someone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a Mac Mini M1. I just removed my very old packages of node.js and npm and decided to install them using homebrew. I found out that now **brew install node** also installs npm. FYI

Answer (score 0):

i tired lot but not help anything. after search lot of blogs i got this one for mac m1 pro.

```
nvm install node
```

this command working fine for me.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I was able to update in ~20 seconds with just one line of code

```
sudo n latest
```

Other commands weren't working for me, but this one worked. Hope it helps somebody.