# npm install hangs on extracting faker

Tags: node.js, ember.js, npm, faker

I'm trying to get working my project based on EmberJS on another computer.
I've cloned the repo, and when I'm trying to run `npm install` it hangs on extracting Faker package.

> extract:faker: verb gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking C:\Users\Babanov.Viktor\PhpstormProjects\IdeaPlannerFront\node_modules.staging\faker-c7ff04ca\node_modules

I tried to wait for a couple of hours, and nothing changed. Removing of the `.stage` directory didn't give any effect.

Here are my `package.json` contents:

```
{
  "name": "idea-planner-ember",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Small description for idea-planner-ember goes here",
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": "",
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "repository": "",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ember build",
    "start": "ember server",
    "test": "ember test"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.4.5",
    "ember-ajax": "^3.0.0",
    "ember-cli": "^2.13.1",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "^3.0.0",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^6.0.0",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^1.3.0",
    "ember-cli-eslint": "^3.0.0",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^1.1.1",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^0.4.0",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.4.1",
    "ember-cli-mirage": "^0.3.1",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "^4.0.0",
    "ember-cli-shims": "^1.1.0",
    "ember-cli-sri": "^2.1.0",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-data": "^2.13.0",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-load-initializers": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-resolver": "^4.0.0",
    "ember-source": "~2.13.0",
    "ember-welcome-page": "^3.0.0",
    "loader.js": "^4.2.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "ember-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.12",
    "ember-simple-auth": "^1.3.0",
    "ember-cli-flash": "^1.4.2",
    "ember-cli-sentry": "^2.4.4"
  }
}
```

Node.js 6.11.2

npm 5.3.0

**UPD.**

I deleted `node_modules` directory, installed `phantomjs-prebuilt`, changed `ember-cli-mirage` version to the latest stable for me (0.3.1) and explicitly installed `faker` with `npm i --save-dev faker@3.0.0` (this version is required by `ember-cli-mirage`). Now when `npm i` npm doesn't try to install `faker` once more. But the error is still here. `npm` hangs on

> extract:core-js: sill extract babel-plugin-eval@1.0.1

I guess it is the next plugin to extract after the `faker`.

Comment: can you provide `package.json` dependencies?

Comment: @SumitRamteke, I've edited the question, thanks

Comment: Remove node-module directory. Try changing version of ember-cli-mirage to `0.3.4`. Check if that works then I will post descriptive answer

Comment: @SumitRamteke I tried to do this but there is no effect.

Comment: Check your node version and relative npm version. Also check if you have done complete ember-cli setup mentioned in their documentation or not. I have tried on my machine with node `7.8` and npm `5.3`. No issues found as such.

Comment: directly deleting node_module in windows might not work. You can use `rimraf` node plugin to deep delete.

Comment: @SumitRamteke I've updated the description with additional info

Comment: Thanks @viktor: I have relatively updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45998299/2443988) as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `ember-cli` is having another dependency called `ember-cli-mirage` which is dependant on `faker`.
- On previous machine, check what versions are there for `node, npm, ember-cli, bower and phantomjs-prebuilt`.
- Either you can use same versions. Or try clearing cache and updating only npm using:

  ```
  npm cache clean
  npm i -g npm
  ```

### Updated Answer

Now that you are receiving following error:

> extract:core-js: sill extract babel-plugin-eval@1.0.1

I dig up more and found that your `loader.js@4.2.3` is using `babel-core@5.x` version which in turn uses `babel-plugin-eval@1.0.1`. If you go to [npm@babel-eval-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-eval), you will find there [github repository](https://github.com/babel-plugins/babel-plugin-eval) link **which no longer exist** and move to [npm@babel-plugin-transform-eval](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-eval). Hence, this issue might be occurring.

Overall, your ember-cli version `2.13.x` is having some not supporting libraries. I will suggest you to upgrade your ember-cli version as mentioned in there [release documentation](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases).

```
npm install -g ember-cli@2.15.1 rimraf
rimraf node_modules dist tmp
npm install --save-dev ember-cli@2.15.1
npm install
ember init
```

I will also suggest to re-clone your repository on fresh location and try these instructions their.

Comment: The previous machine is too far away now. I have the latest (5.3.0) npm.

Comment: Node js version is 6.11.2 (last stable)

Comment: I am not sure if latest latest npm 5.3 supports with node 6.11 LTS or not. But if you want to update Node as well, then go through https://stackoverflow.com/q/23940172/2443988

Comment: I tryed this with npm v5.4.1 and `--no-optional` key. Everything is working now. I don't know what made the final sence because I couldn't do the same with ember-cli 2.15 and npm v5.3 without `--no-optional` key few days ago. But I'm very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly why, but I had the same issue and when changing "something" in my package.json (not a dependency update, just i.e. my package.json version) the npm install worked again.