# npm upgrade with homebrew

Tags: node.js, npm, homebrew

When node (v.0.10.33) is installed with homebrew (v. 0.9.5), at one point it says:

```
==> Caveats
If you update npm itself do NOT use the npm upgrade command
Instead execute:
npm install -g npm@latest
```

So, what exactly is `npm upgrade` and what is the difference with `npm install -g npm@latest`?

**-- edit 2015**

the problem doesn't exist anymore with the current version of node. (but I never had an answer to what `npm upgrade` is?)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11298299/242933

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `npm install` to *install* a package and `npm update` to *update* a package.

That [Homebrew npm caveat was removed](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/commit/f2bfb09f278ad979560920a83bb022d0dd9a6133) after the [issue with `npm update -g`](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4099#issuecomment-94442172) was fixed.

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages#updating-the-package

Answer (score -1):

npm comes bundled with node, both part of Node.js install --- no need to install separately

Below are the steps to install Node.js from source (OSX/linux)
Issue cmds as yourself NOT root (sudo)

to start fresh remove prior node and npm installs as well as these :

```
sudo mv ~/.npmrc ~/.npmrc_ignore
sudo mv ~/.npm   ~/.npm_ignore
sudo mv ~/tmp    ~/tmp_ignore
sudo mv ~/.npm-init.js ~/.npm-init.js_ignore
```

download source from :    http://nodejs.org/download/

```
cd freshly-downloaded-dir
```

define environment variable NODE_PATH as the dir for subsequent module installs

```
export NODE_PARENT=${HOME}/nodejs-v0.10.33
export PATH=${NODE_PARENT}/bin:${PATH}
export NODE_PATH=${NODE_PARENT}/lib/node_modules

./configure   --prefix=${NODE_PARENT}

make
make install   #  IMPORTANT this is NOT using sudo
               # not wanted since installing into $USER owned $NODE_PARENT
```

which puts it into dir defined by above --prefix

when you use syntax :  npm install -g some_cool_module
the -g for global installs it into dir $NODE_PATH and not your $PWD

Now put above three  export xxx=yyy
commands into your ~/.bashrc or some such to persist these environment variable changes

Comment: Thanks, but what's the relationship with homebrew?

Comment: its just a simple source code install, independent of having to use homebrew ... too often I see people getting frustrated with unnecessary  permission issues related to sudo / homebrew / attempting to chown entire /usr/local/   ...  besides this makes explicit the location of node related directories

Comment: ok, but my question is about 1. what is `npm upgrade` (which is not documented)? 2. is it equivalent to `npm install -g npm@latest`?

Comment: The point is installing Node.js gives you both node and npm both.  No need to install npm directly.  The above Caveats notice is coming from source  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/node.rb     the essence of which are my above commands

Comment: the warning from homebrew is not about installing npm separately, but to update it, it uses the `npm ìnstall` command. right?