# Error when upgrade nodes to latest version on Macos

Tags: node.js, macos, upgrade

Now I try to update Nodejs on Macos according to this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284634/upgrade-nodejs-to-the-latest-version-on-mac-os/19333717#19333717). However, one error is here

[image: error image]

When I try to run `Sudo npm install -g n` again, another error comes up

[image: error image1]

Could someone help me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update node, a better way to do it would be to just download the installer again and run it.

https://nodejs.org/en/download/