# How to properly upgrade node using nvm

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm, package-management

Is it possible to upgrade `node` right in place, instead of manually installing the latest stable version?

I have installed [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) version `5.0` with [`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), but now I want to update it to `5.4`. I'm trying to avoid having to manually reinstall all of my global packages (*e.g.* by running `npm install -g grunt-cli bower yo yoman-angular-generator blabla blablablabla`...).

Comment: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm, does installing latest version of NVM removes older versions ?

Comment: @vikramvi thanks for the comment; the question implied upgrading node using nvm, not upgrading nvm itself

Answer (score 620, accepted):

This may work:

```
nvm install NEW_VERSION --reinstall-packages-from=OLD_VERSION
```

For example:

```
nvm install 6.7 --reinstall-packages-from=6.4
```

then, if you want, you can delete your previous version with:

```
nvm uninstall OLD_VERSION
```

Where, in your case,
NEW_VERSION = 5.4
OLD_VERSION = 5.0

Alternatively, try:

```
nvm install node --reinstall-packages-from=current
```

Or you can update to the last long-term support version with

```
nvm install lts --reinstall-packages-from=current
```

Comment: dose using `nvm install stable` remove all the packages installed including installed node rather updating them?

Comment: actually, this is no longer working. There is an issue with npm: https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/811

Comment: By `nvm ls-remote` you can see all releases.

Comment: This works for me: `nvm install node --reinstall-packages-from=$(nvm current)`. That'll update Node.js to latest version and reinstall npm global packages from whatever the previous version was.

Comment: If you fail to uninstall, use `nvm deactivate` and try again.

Comment: the last command fails with error ""stable" is not a valid version or known alias. Available aliases: latest, node (latest), lts". This is a working alternative for the alternative: `nvm install lts --reinstall-packages-from=current`

Answer (score 363):

You can more simply run one of the following commands:

**Latest version**:

```
nvm install node --reinstall-packages-from=node
```

**Stable (LTS) version**: (if currently in use)

```
nvm install "lts/*" --reinstall-packages-from="$(nvm current)"
```

This will install the appropriate version and reinstall all packages from the currently used node version.

This saves you from manually handling the specific versions.

---

Kudos to @m4js7er for commenting about the LTS version.

Comment: If you want to update to latest stable version (lts - recommended for most users), then you should run: `nvm install lts/* --reinstall-packages-from=node`. After that you can cleanup your versions with `nvm uninstall [old version]`. You can list all installed versions with `nvm ls`.

Comment: Double think before doing `--reinstall-packages-from=node` You can use different global environments for versions 6, 8 and 10.

Comment: I tied the command `nvm install lts/* --reinstall-packages-from=node` but it gave me error saying `Version 'lts/*' not found - try 'nvm ls-remote' to browse available versions.` I am using NVM version 0.30.1, maybe my NVM is too old. I end up manually replacing `lts/*` with `10.15.2/*` to get it to work.

Comment: This is the best and easiest command to use to always stay updated..

Comment: If you're on OSX with the default zsh shell and get `zsh: no matches found: lts/*` simply quote the lts/* argument to prevent Z shell from interpreting the * as a globbing wildcard: `nvm install 'lts/*' --reinstall-packages-from=node`

Comment: I was running the current version but, wanted to update the lts version. I wasn't sure if using the flag with a value of node would pull the packages from lts or from current, so I did this instead `nvm install "lts/*" --reinstall-packages-from=14.16.1` Of course, I could have just switched to the old lts but, thought I'd share, in case it was helpful for others.

Comment: When using fish -> `nvm install "lts/*" --reinstall-packages-from=(nvm current)`

Answer (score 56):

> ⚡ **TWO** Simple Solutions:

To install the latest version of node and reinstall the old version packages just run the following command.

```
nvm install node --reinstall-packages-from=node
```

To install the latest `lts` (long term support) version of node and reinstall the old version packages just run the following command.

```
nvm install --lts /* --reinstall-packages-from=node
```

> Here's a **GIF** animation to support this answer:

> [image: nvm]

Comment: Can't get this to work - I just receive `If --reinstall-packages-from is provided, it must point to an installed version of node.`

Comment: @wickywills "node: this installs the latest version of node" maybe you had and LTS or specific version installed and thus `node` did not point to latest version installed. Or you need to update nvm.

Comment: This worked for me but how can I delete the old node after the new one has been installed and activated?

Comment: I know this doesn't exactly answer your question but I've stopped using `nvm` in the favor of an extremely fast and low-profile script called `n`. I made a 10-minute video on it — talking about why I moved to `n` and how you can use it. The video is available at https://nodecli.com/nodejs-install-n

Comment: Isn't it duplicating the existing answer? And the gif animation was distracting for me to read the content, I took the liberty to put it into a spoiler so it becomes available after click so that it is easier to read the content on this page. Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 10):

Here are the steps that worked for me for **Ubuntu** OS and using `nvm`

Go to nodejs website and get the last **LTS** version (for example the version will be: x.y.z)

```
nvm install x.y.z
# In my case current version is: 14.15.4 (and had 14.15.3)
```

After that, execute `nvm list` and you will get list of node versions installed by nvm.

Now you need to switch to the default last installed one by executing:

```
nvm alias default x.y.z
```

List again or run `nvm --version` to check:
[image]

**Update**: sometimes even if i go over the steps above it doesn't work, so what i did was removing the symbolic links in `/usr/local/bin`

```
cd /usr/local/bin
sudo rm node npm npx
```

And relink:

```
sudo ln -s $(which node) /usr/local/bin/nodesudo && ln -s $(which npm) /usr/local/bin/npmsudo && ln -s $(which npx) /usr/local/bin/npx
```

Answer (score 9):

if you have 4.2 and want to install 5.0.0 then

```
nvm install v5.0.0 --reinstall-packages-from=4.2
```

the answer of gabrielperales is right except that he missed the "=" sign at the end. if you don't put the "=" sign then new node version will be installed but the packages won't be installed.

source: [sitepoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-multiple-versions-node-nvm/)

Answer (score 7):

Node.JS to install a new version.

Step 1 : NVM Install

`npm i -g nvm`

Step 2 : NODE Newest version install

`nvm install *.*.*(NodeVersion)`

Step 3 : Selected Node Version

`nvm use *.*.*(NodeVersion)`

Finish

Comment: Currently when you install nvm using npm, you get the response `npm WARN deprecated nvm@0.0.4: This is NOT the correct nvm. Visit http://nvm.sh and use the curl command to install it.`

Answer (score 7):

Here's the steps to upgrade NodeJs version:

1. Run `nvm install node` (will install latest version). Alternatively, you
   can specify a specific version by running `nvm install <node_version>`.
2. Run `nvm use <node_version>` to use it.
3. If you want to make it the default version on your machine, run `nvm alias default <node_version>`.

---

Additional notes:

To find out what node versions you have on your machine and which one is set as your default one, use `nvm list` command.

Answer (score 3):

For **Windows 11** this worked for me on cmd, used with admin rights:

**Prerequisite**, in case you just installed NVM, is to open a new cmd window after nvm installation.

See installation instructions here: https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

1. Get installed versions, using

```
nvm list
```

2. Get current version

```
nvm current
```

3. Install **latest** version

```
nvm install latest
```

4. Check installed versions to see for newer version, again using

```
nvm list
```

5. Set current version to the latest (cmd with admin rights), you just installed in the previous step

```
nvm use PUT_VERSION_NUMBER_TO_BE_USED
```

You can check again if the change was successful using

```
nvm list
```

6. Remove old version, if no longer needed

```
nvm remove PUT_VERSION_NUMBER_TO_BE_REMOVED
```

If you want to use the **LTS** version, install using

```
nvm install lts
```

Comment: Instead of `nvm remove VERSION` it shoud be `nvm uninstall VERSION`

Answer (score 3):

My steps for upgrading node from v16.20.0 to v18.16.0 are as follows

- Run nvm list

```
==> nvm list
->     v16.20.0
       v18.16.0
default -> 16.20.0 (-> v16.20.0)
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
node -> stable (-> v18.16.0) (default)
stable -> 18.16 (-> v18.16.0) (default)
lts/* -> lts/hydrogen (-> v18.16.0)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.24.1 (-> N/A)
lts/erbium -> v12.22.12 (-> N/A)
lts/fermium -> v14.21.3 (-> N/A)
lts/gallium -> v16.20.0
lts/hydrogen -> v18.16.0
```

- Run nvm current

```
==> nvm current
v16.20.0
```

- Run nvm install 18.16.0

```
==> nvm install 18.16.0
v18.16.0 is already installed.
Now using node v18.16.0 (npm v9.5.1)
```

- Run nvm current

```
==> nvm current
v18.16.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Bash alias for updating current active version:

```
alias nodeupdate='nvm install $(nvm current | sed -rn "s/v([[:digit:]]+).*/\1/p") --reinstall-packages-from=$(nvm current)'
```

The part `sed -rn "s/v([[:digit:]]+).*/\1/p"` transforms output from `nvm current` so that only a major version of node is returned, i.e.: `v13.5.0` -> `13`.

Answer (score 0):

I simply run: nvm install 18.17.0 and it worked

Answer (score 0):

```
nvm install <version>
nvm use <version>
```

Looks enough