# React Native Expo - Node.js version 11.13.0 is no longer supported

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo

I'm using Expo with React Native but when trying to create a new project I get the error:

```
ERROR: Node.js version 11.13.0 is no longer supported.

expo-cli supports following Node.js versions:
* >=8.9.0 <9.0.0 (Maintenance LTS)
* >=10.13.0 <11.0.0 (Active LTS)
* >=12.0.0 (Current Release)
```

`$ node --version`

`v11.13.0`

`$ npm install npm@latest -g`

```
...lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
+ npm@6.10.3`
added 6 packages from 4 contributors, removed 11 packages and updated 36 packages in 9.92s
```

`$ node --version`

`v11.13.0`

`$ expo init myApp`

...throws same error above again.

EDIT: 
`$ which node`

`/Users/hasen/.nvm/versions/node/v11.13.0/bin/node`

`$ /usr/local/bin/node --version`

`v10.16.2`

Comment: You're updating npm but not node, try updating node with apt if you're on linux,
or use `npm install -g n` and then `n latest`

Comment: @Onlinogame I looked up how to update node and everywhere said that the procedure is `$ npm install npm@latest -g` to update node.

Comment: I tried what you said and I get `Missing write access to /Users/hasen/.nvm/versions/node/v11.13.0/lib/node_modules/n` not sure why that would be.

Comment: Try using `sudo npm install -g n`

Comment: Ok it worked with sudo but `node -v` is still showing v11.13.0 and I still get the same error with expo. Is it because I'm using nvm? Look at the edit in my question, the node that is being used is in the nvm folder.

Comment: It probably is, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34810526/how-to-properly-upgrade-node-using-nvm

Comment: After `sudo n latest` it shows `installed : v12.8.0 to /usr/local/bin/node` and `active : v11.13.0 at /Users/hasen/.nvm/versions/node/v11.13.0/bin/node`

Comment: @Onlinogame Sorry for the late reply but it took a billion years to install, but from that four year old thread, `nvm install node --reinstall-packages-from=$(nvm current)` worked for me. Post this as an answer and I'll accept it, thanks for your help. Really no idea why so many places say it's npm install latest to update node when in fact it's like you say, it's actually n latest...

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
nvm install node --reinstall-packages-from=$(nvm current)
```

if you're not using nvm :

```
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n latest
```

Comment: this does not help, if I do so I end up with  v15.5.1 which is also not supported

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the `nvm`?

[nvm document Github](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#install-script)

If you did not install the `nvm`,

```
$ curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.4/install.sh | bash
```

And

> Note: If the environment variable `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is present, it
>   will place the `nvm` files there

```
export NVM_DIR="/Users/Chris/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

And

```
nvm install node
```

And

```
node --version
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue because brew was linked to `node` and `nvm` was not the only package manager.

`brew unlink node`.

Answer (score 1):

Just Download the latest NodeJs Version and Install them.

link -: https://nodejs.org/en/download/

currently latest version 14.16.0. Expo works fine with this version.

Answer (score 1):

I had installed the newer version of node using @Onlinogame's

```
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n latest
```

But it wasn't linked. Using sort of the opposite as @Morgan Peters,

```
brew link node
```

Fixed it.