# node -v showing latest version, but my error log has different one

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-compute-engine

I have upgraded my VM node version but my error Log file appears with other version, when i try to build my react application.
`node -v` gives me - `v14.17.5`

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

createRequire is not a function
Referenced from: BaseConfig

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-169-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
npm ERR! node v10.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! epesi-dash-ui@1.0.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

Comment: You can try removing the npm cache and upgrade to the latest version of the node and npm will resolve the issue.
1.`sudo npm cache clean -f` ,


 2.`sudo npm install -g n install n` ,

 3.`sudo n stable`


The first command will force clean the npm package manager's cache, After the second and third commands, a stable version of the node and npm will be installed. then you can execute **npm i** and **npm run build** for creating an optimized production build. Try these commands and let me know if this resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It all happened to be failed update of files in `/usr/local/bin` after `nvm` upgrade.

The following answer solved this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65581673/9530555

Answer (score 0):

After alot of trial and error I managed to fix the issue.
So resetting the symbolic link to correct node location will do the trick.

1. rm -r /usr/bin/node
2. sudo ln -s "$(which node)" /usr/bin/node