# Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]: Only file and data URLs are supported by the default ESM loader - Vue 3

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, vue.js, babel-loader

I get the following error when i want to start my vue 3 typescript project:

```
 ERROR  Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]: Only file and data URLs are supported by the default ESM loader. On Windows, absolute paths must be valid file:// URLs. Received protocol 'c:'
 Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]: Only file and data URLs are supported by the default ESM loader. On Windows, absolute paths must be valid file:// URLs. Received protocol 'c:'
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1016:11)
at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:422:30)
at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:222:40)
at ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:276:22)
at importModuleDynamically (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1041:29)
at importModuleDynamicallyWrapper (node:internal/vm/module:437:21)
at importModuleDynamically (node:vm:381:46)
at importModuleDynamicallyCallback (node:internal/process/esm_loader:35:14)
at loadFileConfig (C:\Projects\backify-ui\documentation\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\util\loadFileConfig.js:28:7)
```

This error occurs since I renamed my `vue.config.js` to `vue.config.mjs`. The funny thing is that this project works via gitpod.io but not in phpstorm and vscode.

My vue.config.mjs:

```
import rehypeHighlight from "rehype-highlight";

export default {
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.module
      .rule("mdx")
      .test(/\.mdx?$/)
      .use("babel-loader")
      .loader("babel-loader")
      .options({ plugins: ["@vue/babel-plugin-jsx"] /* Other options… */ })
      .end()
      .use("@mdx-js/loader")
      .loader("@mdx-js/loader")
      .options({
        jsx: true,
        rehypePlugins: [rehypeHighlight] /* otherOptions… */,
      })
      .end();
  },
};
```

Comment: I'm getting this as well, even using `vue-cli` `5.0.0-rc.1`

Comment: everything is fixed for me in vue cli 5 (beta). More info under the answer of @James Batchelor

Comment: Very strange, neither `5.0.0-rc.1` or `5.0.0-beta.2` are working with me, even with fresh (`yarn cache clean && rm -rf node_modules yarn.lock`) installs. Would you mind saying what OS version you're on, what IDE/shell, etc.?

Comment: here my vue info + global packages: https://i.imgur.com/ZIjoeYT.png

Comment: @V.Rubinetti Did you solve this issue? 5.0.0-rc.1 + node 16.13.0 still not works for me

Comment: Just update to 5.0.8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The whole thing seems to be a bug with the current vue cli configuration and node.js version. For more info check out the comment from @Dima Parzhitsky and @Zhang Buzz.

The best workaround for me was to simply use the `@vue/cli@5.0.0-beta.7` in combination with node `v16.12.0`.

Also i use a `vue.config.mjs` instead of `vue.config.js`

Another solution could be to move the whole thing into the package.json, more about this in the comment of @James Batchelor (but i didn't test it)

Answer (score 60):

My problem is because my Node.js version is too low. Upgrade to Node.js 16 solved the problem.

Answer (score 19):

The issue is because of **the lower version of node** (local). If you **upgrade your node** to the latest version, the issue will be no more. The lower version of node is not compatible with latest webpack.

> I have installed node through nvm(node version manager). So that I can use multiple versions of node. I too face the same issue when I use `node - v12.18.3`. If I use `node - v16.13.1`, problem is fixed.

And this solution is not only for `vue`, It's for all the javascript frameworks including `Angular` and `React`. This is related to latest `webpack`. So if you're using latest webpack with `javascript` code or `typescript` code and lower version of node, the problem will occur.

For the clarity, I've switched to `node - v12.18.3` and try to compile a tyescript code with simple webpack configuration. Below is the error:

```bash
actionanand@RnDlab:/mnt/d/AR/rnd/myJs/sample_ts_code$ npm run serve

> sample_ts_code@1.0.0 serve /mnt/d/AR/rnd/myJs/sample_ts_code
> webpack serve --mode=development

<i> [webpack-dev-server] Project is running at:
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Loopback: http://localhost:8082/
<i> [webpack-dev-server] On Your Network (IPv4): http://192.168.8.107:8082/
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Content not from webpack is served from '/mnt/d/AR/rnd/myJs/index/public' directory
(node:1538) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
<e> [webpack-dev-middleware] HookWebpackError: Only file and data URLs are supported by the default ESM loader
<e>     at makeWebpackError (/mnt/d/AR/rnd/myJs/index/node_modules/webpack/lib/HookWebpackError.js:48:9)
<e>     at /mnt/d/AR/rnd/myJs/index/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:3055:12
<e>     at eval (eval at create (/mnt/d/AR/rnd/myJs/index/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:50:1)
<e>     at /mnt/d/AR/rnd/myJs/index/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:508:26
<e>     at /mnt/d/AR/rnd/myJs/index/node_modules/copy-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:705:13
<e> -- inner error --
<e> Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]: Only file and data URLs are supported by the default ESM loader
<e>     at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:698:11)
<e>     at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:97:40)
<e>     at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:243:28)
<e>     at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:47:40)
<e>     at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:46:36)
<e> caused by plugins in Compilation.hooks.processAssets
<e> Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]: Only file and data URLs are supported by the default ESM loader
<e>     at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:698:11)
<e>     at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:97:40)
<e>     at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:243:28)
<e>     at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:47:40)
<e>     at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:46:36)
```

Once I switch back the node version to higher one (say `node - v16.13.1`), I'm able to compile it successfully.

Answer (score 12):

That actually is a bug.

See, they [use `import()` function](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/packages/@vue/cli-service/lib/util/loadFileConfig.js#L28) on a string, that is the result of [`path.resolve()`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/packages/@vue/cli-service/lib/util/loadFileConfig.js#L17) call. As you have already noticed, the `import()` function [only works with `file://` and `data://` URLs](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#err_unsupported_esm_url_scheme), but `path.resolve()` only returns an absolute path (not a URL), which on Windows environment usually starts with the name of the local disk (e.g., `C:`).

Comment: everything is fixed for me in vue cli 5 (beta). More info under the answer of @James Batchelor.

Comment: Documented in https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/6592 and https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/6667

Comment: are they going to fix? is it happening only on windows?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a possible workaround!

As @Dima Parzhitsky points out, this seems to be a bug in Vue. The part of Vue containing that bug is the loader for the `vue.config.js` (or `.mjs`/`.cjs`) configuration file. Vue actually provides another option though, you can move the configuration to a `"vue":{ ... }` block inside of `package.json`.

[As per the Vue Docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js), this will limit you to only json-compatible values though and since your config uses functions, this might not be an option for you (unless you can find a way of achieving the same result in a json-compatible way)

For those viewing this who *do* have json-compatible values though, here's an example from my own project so you know what it should sort-of look like:

*original `vue.config.js`* (make sure to delete this file):

```
module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
      mainProcessFile: 'src/main/background.js',
      rendererProcessFile: 'src/renderer/main.js',
      externals:['node-pty'],
    },
  },
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        additionalData: `@import "@/renderer/assets/globals.scss";`
      }
    }
  }
};
```

*moved inside `package.json`:*

```
"vue": {
    "pluginOptions": {
      "electronBuilder": {
        "mainProcessFile": "src/main/background.js",
        "rendererProcessFile": "src/renderer/main.js",
        "externals":["node-pty"]
      }
    },
    "css": {
      "loaderOptions": {
        "sass": {
          "additionalData": "@import '@/renderer/assets/globals.scss';"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: It seems that this bug is fixed in vue cli 5 (beta), at least for me. More info here:
https://github.com/mdx-js/mdx/issues/1718

It must be worked according to my experiences and stand now with vue.config.mjs

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue but with pm2 node process manager. I am trying to run a nodejs app in cluster mode, but it always ends in the same error code `[ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]`. This post is the top google result when searching for my issue, so leaving my method of solving it might be helpful to someone.

The solution is to install [Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install)

This allows you to run nodejs in Linux, where the above error can be avoided since the URL scheme would be accepted there. Notice the error message: `Only file and data URLs are supported by the default ESM loader. On Windows, absolute paths must be valid file:// URLs. Received protocol 'c:'`

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue a couple of days ago. I just upgraded node.js to version [16.13.1](https://nodejs.org/es/) and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Clean cache
`yarn cache clean && rm -rf node_modules`

Answer (score 0):

After [updating node by using nvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34810526/how-to-properly-upgrade-node-using-nvm), make sure you also update the version of node that pm2 is running, by the following command:

`pm2 reload app --update-env`:

`pm2 show app` will show you which Node version pm2 is using.

Answer (score 0):

In my case updating yarn was the solution

```
yarn set version stable
```