# X [ERROR] [plugin esbuild-style-plugin] PostCSS config file at E:\...\postcss.config.js can't load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cross-platform, tailwind-css, postcss-loader

Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]: Only file and data URLs are supported by the default ESM loader. On Windows, absolute paths must be valid file:// URLs. Received protocol
'e:'
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1016:11)
at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:422:30)
at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:222:40)
at ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:276:22)
at importModuleDynamically (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1041:29)
at importModuleDynamicallyWrapper (node:internal/vm/module:437:21)
at importModuleDynamically (node:vm:381:46)
at importModuleDynamicallyCallback (node:internal/process/esm_loader:35:14)
at importPostcssConfigFile (E:\Team###NileDashboard\nile-dashboard\node_modules\esbuild-style-plugin\dist\index.js:76:22) {
code: 'ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME'
...

Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]: Only file and data URLs are supported by the default ESM loader. On Windows, absolute paths must be valid file:// URLs. Received protocol
'e:'
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1016:11)
at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:422:30)
at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:222:40)
at ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:276:22)
at importModuleDynamically (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1041:29)
at importModuleDynamicallyWrapper (node:internal/vm/module:437:21)
at importModuleDynamically (node:vm:381:46)
at importModuleDynamicallyCallback (node:internal/process/esm_loader:35:14)
at importPostcssConfigFile (E:\Team###NileDashboard\nile-dashboard\node_modules\esbuild-style-plugin\dist\index.js:76:22) {
code: 'ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME'
}
X [ERROR] [plugin esbuild-style-plugin] PostCSS config file at E:...\postcss.config.js can't load.

when I npm start my react app in windows, I got this error(X [ERROR] [plugin esbuild-style-plugin] PostCSS config file at E:...\postcss.config.js can't load. and also this Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]: Only file and data URLs are supported by the default ESM loader. On Windows10, absolute paths must be valid file:// URLs.
).
I think this project was configured on mac os.
node version 16.13.1

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot speak for Windows, but I was able to resolve this same error on my Linux system by

1. using `Nvm` to update `Node` to a later version

-- [How to properly upgrade node using nvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34810526/how-to-properly-upgrade-node-using-nvm)

-- [How To Install or Update Node by Using nvm](https://dev.to/kovalevski/how-to-install-or-update-node-by-using-nvm-node-version-manager-1ip1)

2. updating the version of node that pm2 was running, by the following command:

`pm2 reload app --update-env`:

### -

- 

More information about it:

`pm2 list` will show the apps pm2 is running e.g. suppose you're only running one, named `app`

`pm2 show app` will show you which Node version pm2 is using. In the output you may see

`node.js version   │    14.20.0`

After updating your `node` version with `nvm`, you need to run

`pm2 reload app --update-env` which should update the version of node that pm2 is using with this process.