# Firebase SDK not working on Google Cloud Console

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

Firebase SDK on Google Cloud Console is not working. Upon using

firebase init

We get

/usr/local/nvm/versions/node/v16.1.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/portUtils.js:9
dns.setDefaultResultOrder("ipv4first");
^

TypeError: dns.setDefaultResultOrder is not a function
at Object. (/usr/local/nvm/versions/node/v16.1.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/portUtils.js:9:5)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1109:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1138:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:989:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:14)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
at Object. (/usr/local/nvm/versions/node/v16.1.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/registry.js:6:19)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1109:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1138:10)

Is anyone having these issues??

Comment: Upgrade the version node installed on your system. The current version is 16.15.1, you are using 16.1.0. IIRC the minimum v16 version is 16.4 or 16.5 (both are old).

Comment: Thank you!  Upon upgrading the node to 16.15.1, it started working!

Comment: Hi @John! Kindly post as an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade the version node installed on your system.

The current version is 16.15.1, you are using 16.1.0. IIRC the minimum v16 version is 16.4 or 16.5 (both are old)

Comment: To upgrade via nvm, this was helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34810922/1459653 (in my case, the command was ```nvm install 16.15.1 --reinstall-packages-from=16.2.0```)