# How to update node js in Laravel homestead on Mac OS?

Tags: node.js, macos, homestead

I have tried several answers to other questions about updating node.js. However, none has worked for me inside the Laravel Homestead in MacOS.

I currently have the 5.12.0 version.

I have tried the following commands:

- `sudo npm install update`
- `sudo npm install -g npm`
- `sudo npm install -g npm@latest`

And after restarting (with --provision) the machine, `node -v` still shows the same version.

Any ideas to update it in Homestead?

**Solved**

I have followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19333717):

- `sudo npm cache clean -f`
- `sudo npm install -g n`
- `sudo n stable`

Then I exited

`exit`

And then I restarted the machine like so:

`vagrant reload --provision`

I typed `node -v` and now it outputs `v6.2.2` and that did the trick.

**However**, these steps did not work in the mac terminal!

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

> apt-get install npm