# Unable to run npm on mac terminal

Tags: node.js, npm, grommet

I have previously installed node and I can see I have version v4.2.2 on my mac when running node -v. I'm now trying to update to latest version of node as well as install grommet.js

When enter on terminal:

npm install npm@latest -g

or

npm install -g grommet-cli

I get

-bash: npm: command not found

I tried resolving with steps in link below without success: 
[Upgrade NodeJS to the latest version on Mac os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284634/upgrade-nodejs-to-the-latest-version-on-mac-os)

How should I go about resolving this one?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that npm might be broken on your system. Might want to try and reinstall npm.

```
curl -L https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

See https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting for additional info.