# Cordova cant add platform

Tags: cordova, cordova-cli

I'm using cordova CLI. I'm trying to add platform but is doesn't work.
Nodejs, npm, android-sdk-linux are all installed.

```
root@hack-ubuntu:/opt/app# cordova platform add android
Adding android project...

/root/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/6.0.0/package/bin/templates/cordova/lib/AndroidStudio.js:16
for(file of eclipseFiles) {
         ^^
Running command: /root/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/6.0.0/package/bin/create /opt/app/platforms/android io.cordova.hellocordova HelloCordova --cli/root/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/6.0.0/package/bin/templates/cordova/lib/AndroidStudio.js:16
for(file of eclipseFiles) {
              ^^
      SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/root/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/6.0.0/package/bin/templates/cordova/lib/AndroidProject.js:24:21)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
Error: /root/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/6.0.0/package/bin/create:Command failed with exit code 8
```

[image]

Comment: Is the browser platform working? `cordova platform add browser`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

In my case, node.js was quite old, and it did not support the new [ES6 loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of):

```
for(file of eclipseFiles) {
```

I followed these steps in order to upgrade node.js:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

[Upgrade NodeJS to the latest version on Mac os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284634/upgrade-nodejs-to-the-latest-version-on-mac-os)