# Update Node.js: Error while updating Node.js on Mac

Tags: node.js, homebrew

I am using mac. I have currently installed Node.js 4.4.3

```
Aleeshas-MacBook-Air:~ aleesha$ node -v
v4.4.3
```

I want to update Node.js to it's latest version by following these [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284634/upgrade-nodejs-to-the-latest-version-on-mac-os).

First I tried to execute: `brew update`. However, I was getting the below error when I executed the command:

> brew update Error: /usr/local is not writable. You should change the
>   ownership and permissions of /usr/local back to your user account:
>   sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local

So after searching for solution on Google, I ran this command: `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local`

After that I  again executed the `brew update` command. I think it was successfully executed since I didn't see any error message. Last few lines on the command prompt were:

> ==> Migrating HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY (please wait)...
>   ==> Migrated HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY to /usr/local/Homebrew! Homebrew no longer needs to have ownership of /usr/local.
>
> If you wish you can
>   return /usr/local to its default ownership with:   sudo chown
>   root:wheel /usr/local Aleeshas-MacBook-Air:~ aleesha$

However after this step when I execute the upgrade command, it failed.

```
Aleeshas-MacBook-Air:~ aleesha$ brew upgrade node
Error: node not installed
Aleeshas-MacBook-Air:~ aleesha$
```

I am not sure what exactly needs to be done here.

Thanks

**EDIT:** Executed `brew doctor` to check for system anomalies.

```
Aleeshas-MacBook-Air:~ aleesha$ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5m-config

Warning: No developer tools installed.
Install the Command Line Tools:
  xcode-select --install


Warning: Python is installed at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework

Homebrew only supports building against the System-provided Python or a
brewed Python. In particular, Pythons installed to /Library can interfere
with other software installs.

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
  /usr/local/include/node/android-ifaddrs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/ares.h
  /usr/local/include/node/ares_version.h
  /usr/local/include/node/libplatform/libplatform.h
  /usr/local/include/node/nameser.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node_buffer.h
```

Comment: It says you don't have node installed. Do you have node installed?

Comment: yes, Version: `v4.4.3`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't install Node using Homebrew, use [this gist](https://gist.github.com/nicerobot/2697848) to uninstall your current installation of Node.

And then:

```
brew update && brew install node
```

Comment: Thanks I had to uninstall and then reinstalled node to the latest version

Comment: Same for me; my [procdeure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47125042/webdriverjs-createsession-args-error/47125235#47125235)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you didn't install nodejs through brew. If you installed Node without brew, brew doesn't recognize it. I had the same issue until I realised that I installed Node with Node Version Manager. Make sure you installed it using Brew.

```
brew list
```

Will show you the things brew installed.

Comment: Thanks, you were right about it. Thanks for the help.