# selenium webdriverjs - createSession(...args) error

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver

I  installed webdriverjs on mac machine  and tried to run a sample script from [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-webdriver-using-the-javascript-bindings--cms-21855) as below

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var browser = new webdriver.Builder().usingServer().withCapabilities({'browserName': 'chrome' }).build();

browser.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki');
browser.findElements(webdriver.By.css('[href^="/wiki/"]')).then(function(links){
    console.log('Found', links.length, 'Wiki links.' )
    browser.quit();
});
```

but I am receiving error

```
static createSession(...args) {}
                       ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
```

node is already installed on my mac

Comment: try to update your node to the latest version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comment above and after searching for an answer , came to know that the error was due to node version. So i had to update my node version.

Here is the process I followed.

When I tried to update node from `brew update
brew doctor
brew upgrade node`

it gave me error `Error: node not installed` , after searching came to know that this is because node on my mac was packaged installation and not through `homebrew` so I had to remove previous installation and install fresh node and I followed [this](https://gist.github.com/nicerobot/2697848) from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41082555/update-node-js-error-while-updating-node-js-on-mac)

Note: If you follow links above and when you do `./uninstall-node.sh` the terminal will stop for you to press `enter`, only then the script will start. Afterwards just do

`brew update && brew install node` to install fresh node. Now `node --version` gives me `v8.9.0` and the the test runs immidiately after upgrading node