# Power Bi Developer Tools Install - Syntax Error

Tags: node.js, installation, powerbi

When installing Power Bi developer tool I get the following error:

```
let exec = require('child_process').execSync;
^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

The time that error message is taken I'm running NodeJS V4.4.7, but I have also tried with versions V5.5.0 and the latest version also. We have it working on another machine but can't seem to run the tool on mine. I am running as Admin.

The setup steps I'm following are from Power BI, [here](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-custom-visuals-getting-started-with-developer-tools/#troubleshooting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you confirmed the node version with `node -v`?

I have just installed `powerbi-visuals-tools`. The node version is v0.12.x and I got the exact same error as yours.

After upgrading node to v6.9.4, the issue is solved. Please make sure you [update node using the same method as before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11298299/2684954).

Comment: Yes I have the same issue with the version! I'll attempt to update the hen when I've got access to my PC

Comment: Hi @DanGardner Does this help solving your issue after all?

Comment: Hi yes apologies it did, I forgot to update the answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Cheers! Glad to help.