# Edit path on macOS Sierra

Tags: path, edit, macos-sierra

When I type: `echo $path` in the terminal on Mac, I get this:

```
/Users/myname/.nvm/versions/node/v5.7.0/bin
```

I needed to upgrade node.js to version 6, so when I upgraded it for some reason now I have two versions installed `v5.7.0` and `v6.11.0`. How can I modify the path so it points to the version `v6.11.0`, i.e. the path becomes:

```
/Users/myname/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/bin
```

I modified `.bash_profile` the as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=$HOME/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/bin:$PATH
source ~/.bashrc
```

But my path does not change.

Comment: Check this answer once : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284634/upgrade-nodejs-to-the-latest-version-on-mac-os

Comment: I tried that answer, but it doesn't change the path!

Comment: uninstall the node and install latest version

Comment: How shall I do that?

Comment: brew uninstall node

Comment: I get this error: ~ brew uninstall node
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/node