# Upgrade NodeJS to LTS 8 on Mac OS with brew

Tags: node.js, macos

Since node 8 LTS [has been released](https://nodejs.org/en/) I am intending to upgrade my current version v6.11.4 to version v8.9.0 on macOS Sierra.

Tried `brew upgrade node` and looked it worked, but when doing `node -v` still getting v6.11.4.

If I try `brew upgrade node` **again** am getting `Error: node 8.9.0 already installed` as below.

[image: Trying to upgrade node to v8.9.0 on macOS Sierra]

**Note 1**: I am not using nvm.

**Note 2**: I had found the following [question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284634/upgrade-nodejs-to-the-latest-version-on-mac-os), but none proposal there worked for me, maybe because it's five years old.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What does `which node` print?

Comment: console prints `/usr/local/bin/node`

Comment: Try `brew link node; node -v`

Comment: It worked, thanks!
I ended up doing `brew link --overwrite node`

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it is a symlink issue.

`brew link --overwrite node` fixes it.

Console outputs `Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/8.9.0... 144 symlinks created`