# Can't upgrade to the LTS version of node

Tags: node.js

I tried to follow the steps of the accepted answer of this link [Upgrade NodeJS to the latest version on Mac os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284634/upgrade-nodejs-to-the-latest-version-on-mac-os) to upgrade my `node.js` version from `6.11.1` to `8.11.2`

but after I execute `node --version` it's still `v6.11.1`

- `sudo npm cache clean -f`
- `sudo npm install -g n`
- `sudo n lts`

its still no changes.

Comment: sadly `n` doesn't work for me. so i use `nvm` and it worked like a charm

Comment: I would suggest you look at [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). Makes life easy with node version management