# Gulp error after upgrading node to v10.4.1

Tags: node.js, gulp

I am running on Mac OS X. I've recently updated node and npm to the latest version, following these accepted answer steps [Upgrade Node.js to the latest version on Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284634/upgrade-node-js-to-the-latest-version-on-mac-os) . Node: `v10.4.1` and  npm: `6.1.0` And now when I run my Gulp file, I am getting this error:

```
gulp[2838]: ../src/node_contextify.cc:629:static void node::contextify::ContextifyScript::New(const FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &): Assertion `args[1]->IsString()' failed.
 1: node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
 2: node::MakeCallback(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Object>, char const*, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*, node::async_context) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 3: node::contextify::ContextifyScript::New(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 4: v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(v8::internal::CallHandlerInfo*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 5: v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::Object> v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::HandleApiCallHelper<true>(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FunctionTemplateInfo>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::BuiltinArguments) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 6: v8::internal::Builtin_Impl_HandleApiCall(v8::internal::BuiltinArguments, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 7: 0x211117841bd
 8: 0x2111178ee5d
 9: 0x2111180b2a0
10: 0x21111793429
11: 0x21111793429
12: 0x21111793429
Abort trap: 6
```

Does anyone know what is the issue here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A complete artical about this: 
https://davidsekar.com/nodejs/upgrading-your-gulp-for-running-with-node-v10

## resume:

gulp 3.x doesn't work with node 10.x

remove gulp

```
npm rm -g gulp
```

install gulp-cli (a gulp-cli package was introduced, check it here https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-cli)

```
npm i gulp-cli -g
```

install gulp v4 locally in your project

```
npm i gulp@next --save-dev
```

Last thing you need **to make changements to your gulpfile.js**, **syntax and features changed**. So read the artical for that, it's simple and straight forward.
[Here it is again](https://davidsekar.com/nodejs/upgrading-your-gulp-for-running-with-node-v10).

Comment: Gulp v4.0.2 resolved this error for my environment node v10.16.3, npm v6.9.0.

Answer (score 6):

Don't understand why but run `npm i natives` solved the problem for me.

Comment: That's right. I had gulp -v `3.9.1` and npm -v `v11.12.0`, but running this command `npm i natives` fixed it for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All I needed to do is to update my Gulp version also. Running `npm rebuild node-sass` fixed my issue

Comment: Which version were you at and what did you change it to?