# (node:9511) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, import, require

I am trying to use ES6 on server side. I a have separated endpoint from server file:

archive.js:

```
import { Router } from "express";
const router = Router();

router.get("/", async (req, res) => { "some code"});

export default router;
```

when i want to import it to my server file like this:

```
import archive from "./endpoints/archive.js";
app.use("/archive", archive);
```

it gives me an error:

(node:9565) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
internal/modules/run_main.js:54
internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException()

any idea guys? i dont want to go back to require/module.exports

Comment: What version of nodejs?  By default a `.js` file is assumed to be a CommonJS file, NOT an ESM module unless you have appropriately tagged it in a package.json file.  It is much easier to get ESM modules to work by making them `.mjs` files, not `.js` files because the loader assumes any `.mjs` file is an ESM module.  Which file does this warning/error occur in?

Comment: This was a new directory which i have pulled from github repo. I have tried many things/solutions but it turned out i have to clone to a new directory/environment.
Couldnt find the problem or a proper fix but in the new directory/environment i dont have that problem.

Answer (score 14):

you can use  Node v14.12.0; where this probleme is solved, and read this doc https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_package_json_type_field

Answer (score 3):

I realize after a few tries that "--experimental-modules" flag on the "nodemon" causes issues to realize the imports in the whole app so I did update that flag to use the new flag for explicit filenames"--es-module-specifier-resolution=node" and now works perfect here is an article about this new flag  :  https://nodejs.medium.com/announcing-a-new-experimental-modules-1be8d2d6c2ff

So for explane you can do a script like this:

```
nodemon --es-module-specifier-resolution=node
```

Also keep in mind the nodejs version you use a version under 12.XX, 14.XX or the last stable version.

[Upgrade Node.js to the latest version on Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284634/upgrade-node-js-to-the-latest-version-on-mac-os)

I hoper this helps more developers :)

Comment: I needed to update Node ️