# Uninstalling / Removing npm and node package on Mac

Tags: node.js, npm, osx-mavericks, homebrew

I am trying to remove the package download of npm and node that I installed to install them with Homebrew instead. However I am having great difficulty in doing this. How can I get the package version of node.js and npm totally removed from my Mac so I can install the Homebrew version?

Note: I have tried `sudo npm rm --global node` however I get the error `sudo: npm: command not found`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044788/how-do-i-uninstall-nodejs-installed-from-pkg-mac-os-x

Comment: now I am getting the error `Warning: node-0.10.31 already installed, it's just not linked` how can I rectify this?

Comment: if I try to install phonegap I get this error `sudo: npm: command not found`

Answer (score -1):

check the link below for uninstalling node/npm

[How do I uninstall nodejs installed from pkg (Mac OS X)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044788/how-do-i-uninstall-nodejs-installed-from-pkg-mac-os-x)

and the brew error is happening due to permmision issue.
Since brew basically don't allow to be executed with `sudo` so change the directory permission before brew command.

changing permission:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:admin /usr/local
```

brew link command:

```
brew link node
```

and then you can use `npm` or `node` commands.

Comment: its just a really bad suggestion to change ownership of /usr/local