# How can I uninstall io.js correctly on Mac OS X El Capitan?

Tags: node.js, iojs

I cannot find any instructions for correctly uninstalling io.js from Mac OS X. The only guide i can find online is here, but the directory it mentions for io.js doesn't seem to exist on my computer, or I don't know where to look: https://www.binarysludge.com/2015/01/14/how-to-uninstall-io-js-or-io-js-and-node-js-together/

I think I've got a real mess with node/npm/nvm/io.js, and don't think i can start working out how to set everything up correctly unless i can figure out how to get rid of io.js.

I installed io.js using the package from the website for Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

On the similar question was already given a detailed answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044788/how-do-i-uninstall-nodejs-installed-from-pkg-mac-os-x)

For delete it run commands in terminal:

```
sudo npm uninstall npm -g
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules /var/db/receipts/com.nodesource.iojs.*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/node /Users/$USER/.npm
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/iojs    
sudo rm /usr/local/share/man/man1/iojs.1
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d
sudo rm /usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
```