# Error: Cannot find module '@angular/tsc-wrapped/src/tsc' ionicjs ionic view

Tags: npm, ionic3, ionic-view, tsc

I get following error when try to compile ionic 3 app with ionic-view ([www.ionicjs.com](http://www.ionicjs.com))

```
Error: Cannot find module '@angular/tsc-wrapped/src/tsc'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object. (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:7:13)
at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
npm info lifecycle MedMan@0.0.1~build: Failed to exec build script
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! MedMan@0.0.1 build: `ionic-app-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the MedMan@0.0.1 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/gitlab-runner/.npm/_logs/2017-09-25T14_14_22_583Z-debug.log
/snapshot.sh: line 32: [: missing `]'
npm run build failed
Make sure your project has a build script in the package.json
Failed to upload build to storage please retry your build.
Running after script...
$ clean-up
Cleaning up files...
Successful clean up
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

I work with following Versions:

```
"@angular/tsc-wrapped": "4.4.3",
"@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.4.1"
"ionic": "3.12.0",
"rxjs": "^5.4.3",
"tslint": "^5.7.0",
"tslint-loader": "^3.5.3"

npm v 4.6.1
node v 8.5.0
```

None of the solutions at the web can solve this issue for me.

Answer (score 5):

I guess this should fix it:

- upgrade `npm` to the latest version (`5.3.0`), I personally stayed at `5.1.0` because there were issues with ionic and version `5.2.0` but I think it is fixed in the current version
- `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json` (on Windows: delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` manually)
- `npm install`

If it still does not work you can try to manually install tsc-wrapped:

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/tsc-wrapped
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me (updated npm to 5.3.0, tsc-wrapped manually). I also tried: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cannot-find-angular-tsc-wrapped-while-doing-an-ionic-serve/97853/5

Comment: Then reinstall node.

Comment: reinstallation doesn't help. Did this to deinstall node: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044788/how-do-i-uninstall-nodejs-installed-from-pkg-mac-os-x

Comment: Then either your system is toast or you made some mistake during installation.

Comment: I made a new ionic project and copied the files. Now it is working.

Comment: npm install --save-dev @angular/tsc-wrapped worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
npm install npm@latest -g
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g angular-cli@latest
npm install @angular/tsc-wrapped autoprefixer
```

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3183#issuecomment-261740427

I additionally had to (but dont think this is only related to my case):

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```