# Node.js - env: node: No such file or directory when running `which`

Tags: node.js, bash, terminal, environment-variables, macos-sierra

I removed node.js from my mac using:

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044788/how-do-i-uninstall-nodejs-installed-from-pkg-mac-os-x)

[and this](https://gist.github.com/nicerobot/2697848)

Now whenever I run `which something` on the terminal

I get: `env: node: No such file or directory`

My path: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands`

Comment: Run `set -x` before your `which` command to log what it's actually doing. That'll be useful if it's either an alias or a shell function.

Comment: And btw, in general, you should be using `type` instead of `which` in the first place. (Indeed, on that point, the output of `type which` may be informative).

Comment: which is /usr/local/bin/which

Comment: set -x produces logs but I don't know how to make sense of it

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/which`, not `/usr/bin/which`? That's your problem. Delete it. (The Apple-provided copy of `which` is in `/usr/bin`; the `/usr/local/bin` one comes from somewhere else).

Comment: Yes apparently, what could have caused this?

Comment: Something you installed that depends on `node` trying to provide its own copy of `which`. Since I don't know what you installed, how could I say?

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Did not expect a specific answer but just the general info that something depending on node installed this